# Swedish keyboard disappeared after upgrading to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, keyboard-layout

After upgrading from 20/04 to 22.04 all of a sudden my keyboard obviously works with another layout than my physical keyboard. For instance does shift plus 7 normally give slash but now I get & instead.
Anyone who knows how to fix this.
I have seen in my settings that I am supposed to have a Swedish keyboard, but when I open that it sure is not the correct layout. Here is what I get
[keyboard layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oy94o.png)

Comment: Not sure why this happens but this might be of some use to you. I use English and Swedish in the OS and often switch between them. Every once in a while for a reason I can not find I have to switch from Swedish where I usually keep the keyboard to English and back again to get the Swedish keyboard layout to be the active one.

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` Try this.